# can not upgrade kernel

Tags: centos, kernel

I use centos-7 x86_64 ，current kernel version is 2.6.32-042stab108.5
I try to upgrade kernel by these command:

```
rpm -Uvh http://www.elrepo.org/elrepo-release-7.0-2.el7.elrepo.noarch.rpm 
yum install --enablerepo=elrepo-kernel kernel-ml
```

and the respones is

```
Package kernel-ml-4.2.4-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

but the uname -a output is still

```
2.6.32-042stab108.5
```

so is it upgrade success?

Comment: I also reboot but nothing changes

Answer (score 1):

The reason why `uname -r` reports "2.6.32-042stab108.5" is because your CentOS system is running as an [OpenVZ container](https://openvz.org/Download/kernel/rhel6/042stab108.5) (with an out of date kernel, to boot).  You'll need to work with your hosting provider to see if they let you boot your own kernel rather than their default hosting kernel.  It won't matter what kernel package you have installed.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you rebooted your system after the upgrade. If so, then it failed as your system is clearly still using the older kernel.

If the automatic upgrade failed, manually check the configuration of your boot loader and make sure the correct image is called on boot.

If this is a virtual internet host, there is a possibility that you have access to a containerized system only. In this case, you cannot change the Kernel yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Not related to CentOS only, but ... sometimes you should check if boot manager configuration is up to date. Boot manager should be autoconfigured to use new kernel just after new kernel is installed. It should be done automatically but sometimes it doesn't happen.
For example: I'm using Gentoo and I need to use `grub2-mkconfig` any time I update my kernel to update configuration and I'm doing this manually otherwise my system will continue to boot using previous version.

So, you should check your boot manager configuration and be sure that there is an entry for the new kernel and (optional) make it default choice or just select respective entry form choice screen at boot time.

However, to check if new kernel is installed use this command:
`rpm -qa | grep "kernel-m1"`