# CentOS update from 7.1 to 7.2 with 2.6 OpenVZ kernel?

Tags: centos, kernel, upgrade, virtual-machine

We are using CentOS 7.1:

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)
```

We deferred the 7.2 upgrade. It looks like it did not cause any problems so we are planning an upgrade. The wrinkle for us is:

```
$ uname -a
Linux cryptopp 2.6.32-042stab112.15 #1 SMP Tue Oct 20 17:22:56 MSK 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

We think the 2.6 kernel is present because of hosting and an [OpenVZ container](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/238317). I tried to research if the CentOS QA team tested the configuration, but I could not find information on it (cf., no discussion of OpenVZ in the [release notes](http://wiki.centos.org/Manuals/ReleaseNotes/CentOS7)).

Is it safe to perform the upgrade from 7.1 to 7.2 with the 2.6 kernel? That is, is this a supported configuration that will update as expected?

If not, what are our options?

Comment: I bite... How, exactly, is this opinion based? The configurations is either tested and supported or its not. I can't find information on either.

Comment: That is strange. Check grub.conf -- it might be you are running an alternate configuration, or that the system was upgraded from 6 to 7 (I don't know if that's really possible) and the default kernel level wasn't changed.